# How do I escape @ mentions in comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

When commenting, I recently came across an issue when I needed to explain instance variables using the Ruby syntax @variablename; of course, I'm only allowed to mention one user per comment, so this proved tricky.

How do I stop comments from automatically creating user links when @ is used, and simply be interpreted as plain text?

Comment: When I read this title, I thought you meant "escape" as in "run away from". Disappointed that you're not fleeing from your inbox  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a keyboard layout that doesn't have the backtick, use *\@* instead of *@*. That avoids the character is thought to be a @-reference, and allows it to be used.
I am using the Italian keyboard layout, and the keyboard doesn't have the backtick. (I have to use the *Italian 142* layout, and switch to it when I need to print a back-tick.)

Doing this shows up the backslash, but if you don't have a keyboard with the backtick, this at least avoids the warning message.

If you are using a keyboard that allows you to enter a backtick without changing keyboard layout, since you are referring to a variable name, you can simply wrap the variable name with backticks (e.g. `@variablename`) which works on comments too.
In my case, I switch to the *Italian 142* layout and press <kbd>alt-gr</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd> just for the time to write the backticks; then I switch back to the usual Italian layout, which allows me to enter *#*, *[*, or *]*.

Comment: Simple, really should have thought of that. Cheers.

Comment: Sadly the \ still shows up, but this does work

Comment: @Yule This should work too: `@variablename`.

Comment: @Yule \@variablename shows the backslash, which could not be what you want.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yes, I should have make that clear. I reported this trick for those users who don't have the backtick in their keyboard. I am using the Italian keyboard, and outputting a backtick is not that easy: It requires using a second Italian keyboard layout which then doesn't make possible to output other characters.

Answer (score 17):

Use backticks `` ` ``  to make the @ mention into an inline code block.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, however not applicable in this case as wouldn't want the text to look like code in this particular scenario. Good to know you can do this though

Comment: @Yule Admittedly, I like kiam's suggestion better, but isn't your `@variable` representing something in the code anyway? Hehe.

Comment: It is representing something in the code, but it's not actual code. It's discussing the use of \@variables, rather than a particular \@variable in the question

Comment: I think this approach looks more natural in most cases. +1